# Django compatible web hosting services

Tags: python, django, hosting, web-hosting

What is your favorite (free or not) web hosting services that is compatible with django( and python in general) ?

PS: is OVH compatible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Options are several, depending on whether you want to do any work or not:

---

- As long as you don't want to do anything, you should go for hosting which does it for you:

  1. [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) - included IDE in cloud
  2. [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) - in basic use free, but any addon can be pricy.
     If you would like to deploy some code I have made a fork with an update in full process description of deployment to heroku -> [tutorial on github](https://github.com/YoungCoder/heroku-django-cms)
  3. [webfaction](https://www.webfaction.com/features) - Python, Ruby, Perl, PHP
  4. [linode](https://www.linode.com/) - as many say the best integration for non specialist in system administration

---

- As long as you can do system configuration, I would go for VPS options such as OVH, which for my personal use I find the cheapest (approx. 10 EUR/month) which for this spec is kind of a good deal -> 1 vCore (2.0 GHz+)    1 GB    50 GB   100 Mbit/s  10,10 €

---

Place where you can find many free hosting services for django ->
http://freedjangohosting.com/

Comment: you sir deserve more likes :-)

Comment: now with the VPS affordable prices, django dedicated hosting don't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 6):

[WebFaction](http://webfaction.com/) is among the best in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah !! webfaction!!